# Add hours to TimeCreated received from Get-WinEvent

Tags: powershell, datetime, logging, event-log

I have the below command:

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{
  Logname      = 'Application'
  ID           = 1000
  ProviderName = 'Application Error'
} -MaxEvents 1 | select TimeCreated
```

I get the below as output:

```
TimeCreated
-----------
04-Jan-16 11:29:11 PM
```

I want this value to be saved into a variable and add two hours into it, like this:

```
$ErrorTime = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{
               Logname      = 'Application'
               ID           = 1000
               ProviderName = 'Application Error'
             } -MaxEvents 1 | select TimeCreated

$Time1 = ($ErrorTime).AddHours(2)
```

But doing the above is not giving me the desired answer. It is not storing the time as value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to expand the `TimeCreated` property of the event object to get the `DateTime` value:

```
$ErrorTime = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{
               Logname      = 'Application'
               ID           = 1000
               ProviderName = 'Application Error'
             } -MaxEvents 1 | Select-Object -Expand TimeCreated

$Time1 = $ErrorTime.AddHours(2)
```

You can get the date and time portion of the timestamp via the object's `Date` and `Time` properties:

```
$date = $Time1.Date
$time = $Time1.Time
```

Comment: Thanks Ansgar, that worked perfect.

Could you also tell me a way to split the date and time part and save it in two separate variables . I need to put that in the log file name.

Also, could you please viewthis question of mine.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34693760/wevtutil-equivalent-for-powershell-script

Comment: Awesome!
Thanks a ton!